# How to execute script python when i click button in form html?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

hello how can i run script that i build on python when i click button on form html

i saw examples like this but i dont get it:

Html code: index.html

```
<form action="{% url my_view %}" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

views.py

```
import django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       import set_gpio
       #my url is "templates/load.py"

   return #How can i return?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an [HttpResponse object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) from your view. You can return one response inside your if statement, and another outside of it (so anything but a POST). Usually the [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render) is used to render a response from a template. So your view would be something like:

```
import django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       # The user clicked the button (POST)
       return render(request, "load.html")

   # The user is just loading the view for the first time (GET)
   return render(request, "index.html")
```

I highly suggest going through the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/).

Comment: ok i see... but when i try to load page print an error: ImportError: No module named core...

in line: <form action="{% url my_view %}" method="POST">

Answer (score 0):

You have to realise that Django is a HTTP based framework meaning that when an HTTP request is sent to a url, Django will be allowed to perform an action. So, every function is actually a reaction to the HTTP requests that the user sends to your urls.
Also, if you are using Django template system, the `html` file should be rendered by Django in the first place. So, you cannot have a standalone `html` file with `{% url my_view %}` in it. 

First, you have to configure the main `urls.py` which is in a folder with the same name as your project.

Second, in your app, create an `urls.py` file and configure it.

At the end, you connect your `my_view` to a specific or set of urls and will be triggered when a request is sent to that url, whether GET or POST. 

These are somewhat large (and easy) topics for which you have to watch a tutorial or read the Django documentations.